# Could someone recommend an excellent book on optimal control theory for partial differential equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control

I am a researcher in optimal control theory, particularly focusing on PDEs. I have extensively studied many of J-L Lions' excellent books in this field, as well as Fredi Tröltzsch's outstanding work. I am seeking additional insightful literature that could provide fresh perspectives and new ideas for my research. Could you kindly recommend some books that align with these interests? Thank you!

Comment: https://books.google.sh/books?id=dyjrBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Jeff Thanks a lot!